# 2.4inch 8bit bus LCD ili9341 doen't work with STM32F103

Tags: c, stm32, lcd

I bought a LCD device written on the title on ebay and tried to drive through `stm32F103` didn't work and I'm kind of stuck.(I modified `ili9341` library for `arduino` I found in `github` for `stm32` ) I started doubting this LCD isn't `ili9341` and I ran program of Register Read and ran this thing on `stm32` and says...

```
reg(0x0000 ) 00 00 ID: ILI9320, ILI9325, ILI9335, ...　

reg(0x0004 ) 00 00 00 00 Manufacturer ID

reg(0x0009 ) 00 00 61 00 00 Status Register

reg(0x000A ) 00 08 Get Power Mode

reg(0x000C ) 00 06 Get Pixel Format

reg(0x0061 ) 00 00 RDID1 HX8347-G

reg(0x0062 ) 00 00 RDID2 HX8347-G

reg(0x0063 ) 00 00 RDID3 HX8347-G

reg(0x0064 ) 00 00 RDID1 HX8347-A

reg(0x0065 ) 00 00 RDID2 HX8347-A

reg(0x0066 ) 00 00 RDID3 HX8347-A

reg(0x0067 ) 00 00 RDID Himax HX8347-A

reg(0x0070 ) 00 00 Panel Himax HX8347-A

reg(0x00A1 ) 00 00 00 00 00 RD_DDB SSD1963

reg(0x00B0 ) 00 00 RGB Interface Signal Control

reg(0x00B4 ) 00 02 Inversion Control

reg(0x00B6 ) 00 0A 82 27 04 Display Control

reg(0x00B7 ) 00 06 Entry Mode Set

reg(0x00BF ) 00 00 00 00 00 00 ILI9481, HX8357-B

reg(0x00C0 ) 00 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 Panel Control

reg(0x00C8 ) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 GAMMA

reg(0x00CC ) 00 72 Panel Control

reg(0x00D0 ) 00 00 00 Power Control

reg(0x00D2 ) 00 00 00 03 03 NVM Read

reg(0x00D3 ) 00 00 93 41 ILI9341, ILI9488

reg(0x00D4 ) 00 00 00 00 Novatek ID

reg(0x00DA ) 00 00 RDID1

reg(0x00DB ) 00 00 RDID2

reg(0x00DC ) 00 00 RDID3

reg(0x00E0 ) 00 0F 16 14 0A 0D 06 43 75 33 06 0E 00 0C 09 08 GAMMA-P

reg(0x00E1 ) 00 08 2B 2D 04 10 04 3E 24 4E 04 0F 0E 35 38 0F GAMMA-N

reg(0x00EF ) 00 03 80 02 02 02 ILI9327

reg(0x00F2 ) 00 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 Adjust Control 2

reg(0x00F6 ) 00 01 00 00 Interface Control
```

So this part `reg(0x00D3 ) 00 00 93 41 ILI9341, ILI9488` says 9341 means it actually is `ili9341` and I should keep using `ili9341` driver? (Which means I need to recheck my code again?)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's difficult to understand your question. What sort of help would you like from the community? Please consider rephrasing your question, add the code you have so far and better describe what *didn't work* means.

Comment: My question is if the driver IC is ILI9341 ? (Since on ebay sometimes the seller says it's ili9341 LCD and it's actually not ) Doesn't work mean it doesn't display anything after initialization program and sending order to display some colors from stm32 with ili9341 driver I've written.